# Can the public link in Files be limited to logged in users?

Tags: community, files

We have a private (authenticated) community that is intended to include content (Files and Knowledge articles) that is only available to logged in users.

We are trying to share files to our external users that have a Community license. We've heard that this is only available to external users with Community+ licenses.

Is it possible to use a "public" link to Files that requires authentication?

Alternatively, are you able to share files in libraries to users on a Community license?

Answer (score 0):

You can publicly share password protected Content, and share the password with your community users —note for each Document you'll have to share a different auto-generated password, if this is not an issue, then this could be a good approach for your problem. [Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_delivery_about.htm&type=5)

Alternatively you could migrate your licenses to Customer Community + which has access to Content since —like you mentioned above— Customer Community does not support Content.